# Does JSch library support dynamic port forwarding?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, socks

I'm trying to implement dynamic port forwarding (ssh -D) in my application, I already use JSch to establish ssh connections to remote hosts. I see JSch has support for Local and Remote port forwarding but i'm not sure about Dynamic Port Forwarding.
 Is it supported ? Are there other ssh clients that support it ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but according to the code and the examples only [local](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingR.java.html) and [remote port forwarding](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java.html) is supported.

The `com.jcraft.jsch.Session` object only provides the methods `setPortForwardingR` and `setPortForwardingR`.
So my best guess is that dynamic port forwarding is not supported.